Creation of a smart contract in contracts pallet
I need to create a smart contract using contracts pallet. I look at the source code of the contracts pallet and see:
pub fn upload_code(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    code: Vec<u8>,
    storage_deposit_limit: Option<<BalanceOf<T> as codec::HasCompact>::Type>,
    determinism: Determinism,
) -> DispatchResult {
    Migration::<T>::ensure_migrated()?;
    let origin = T::UploadOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)?;
    Self::bare_upload_code(origin, code, storage_deposit_limit.map(Into::into), determinism)
        .map(|_| ())
}

So I have to pass a hash of already deployed smart contract, but I need to create a smart contract as a specific account, so how to do it?
Sorry that I am wandering and I do not have clear thinking about all dots. The context of the question is the test.

I have found one of the possible solution, using instantiate function, documentation.
#[test]
fn contract_instantiate_works() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        let _ = env_logger::try_init();
        let contract_address = instantiate("path/to/ink/contract/my_contract.wasm", INIT_VALUE, vec![]);
}

